# Merge 2 arrays of Json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Combine two API feeds from different sources and aggregate them into one.

I.e. one from The Guardian News Paper, another from The New York Times. I'd these results to then be combined to display as one feed.

I'd be pulling the data from each source as JSON

At this stage i'm just trying to understand how i'd achieve this if I can achieve it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well. Yes. Request one. Request the other. Read the data from both. Combine them however you like (with whatever transformation, sorting, etc, you like) Write out some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each query returns proper JSON you'd then have 2 arrays of JS objects. You're really just dealing with how to merge 2 arrays of objects.

Since there's a good chance each API will return different formatting I'd suggest 2 loops to iterate over each response to put the data into your own array of objects.

Some made up from the New York Times:

```
var ntyData = [{headline: 'Something Awful has happened!', published: 1462539770}]
```

And some fake data from The Guardian:

```
var tgData = [{subject: 'Zoo Welcomes Baby Panda', pub: 1232530000}]
```

Create an array to hold your parsed data and iterate over each response.

```
var parsedData = [];

nytData.forEach(function(article) {
    parsedData.push({
        title: article.headline,
        time_published: article.published
    });
});

tgData.forEach(function(article) {
    parsedData.push({
        title: article.subject,
        time_published: article.pub
    });
});
```